# How to prevent user from changing item name in PayPal button?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using a PayPal generated button that is hosted on their servers but it seems that if I take the code and pass into it a new item name it will also change the item name on the PayPal page:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="testname">
```

I've also tried this for price and **it remains the same as before**, so that's ok. But for some reason it seems you can change the item name by adding this line.
How do I prevent this?

I don't want users hacking buttons because I use the item name with IPN to send the file to the user after he purchased.

Comment: OT but it seems to me that if you have a detected and provable fraud on the part of someone who's paid you some money like this you just keep the funds and don't deliver the goods or services. You don't need to reject anything, and you don't need to go to extraordinary lengths to prevent it.

Comment: @EJP The issue is when they can replace the item name with something worth more. Eg. purchase something that costs $2 and change the item name to a more valuable product to pay less for it. In any case, using item_number is the safest bet.

Comment: I understand that you have to *detect* the fraud, but it's still a fraud. Don't prevent; don't deliver; don't refund; don't advise. Let them chase you, and in that unlikely event defend vigorously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I guess I figured it out. For some odd reason, even though the button is hosted to PayPal, you can change the item name. I found that's the only thing you can change though.

To make sure the purchase goes well, even though the name can be changed, you can assign a code to each button when you create it (in PayPal). Then in your database group that code with the real item name. This way you can use the code to get the item name later when the IPN validation happens.

Comment: Do you mean you can change the *item* name? Your answer says you can change the button name.

Comment: @EJP Yeah, I meant "item name". I've corrected it. And it would seem it can be changed even though the button is hosted to PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to register the order in your database before you send them to the payment page. After the payment you can compare the payment information with the information you stored in the database.

On this way you will be able to detect it when they edit input fields.

Comment: that still won't solve it. I want them to be unable to pay if the item name is incorrect or do something to make them unable to change the item name at all.